# google maps search by label does not work anymore

Tags: search, google-search, label, google-maps

Since around February 2024 I can not search locations by self-added labels anymore.

E.g. my parking spot has the label "p9 parking". In the past, it was enough to type p9 to be able to select this location either on my mobile as on my notebook. Now it does not even appear if I type the complete label in the search.

**Plattform:**

I have this issue as well on

- Chrome on my Ubuntu 22.04 Notebook and on
- the google maps app on my Android phone

**Issues of other users:**

In February 2022 a user posted the same issue in the Google support forum:

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/149985771/can-t-search-by-saved-places-labels-anymore?hl=en

Though no one posted a solution over there.

**Suspected fault localization:**

I tested the functionality with a different account and there it works as I want.

Based on where and when the issue is happening I assume it is not a matter of the device or software version but with the user settings.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?